# Material UI Tooltip does not appear when rendered inside of a custom Modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, modal-dialog, popup

Here is how my custom Modal component is defined:

```
function Modal({ open, set_open, children }) {
  const modal_ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      modal_ref.current.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      modal_ref.current.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, [open]);

  return ReactDom.createPortal(
    <div className="modal-container" ref={modal_ref}>
      <div className="modal-content">{children}</div>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
```

The children property of the component will contain the tooltip. Or it may actually be the grandchildren.

But either way, it should appear, no?

Comment: It can be a z-index problem. please increase the z-index of the tooltip larger than the modal

Comment: I tried that. I applied the highest zIndex to the style property of the Tooltip. Didn't work

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.MuiTooltip-popper {
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

As much as I hate using `!important`, that's what did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this via a mui theme override as well.

```
export default function ThemeProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const theme = createTheme({
    zIndex: { tooltip: 99999 },
  });

  return (
    <MUIThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {children}
    </MUIThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this has a side-effect of resetting all other styling to defaults.